# XML-based databases as with SQL?

Tags: sql, xml

Is it possible to store data as plain XML files and be able to search and sort information as in SQL? Various applications I have in mind are simple phonebooks, bookmarks lists, passwords lists for personal use.

For example:

```
<accounts>
  <account>
    <website>mail.google.com</website>
    <username>example@gmail.com</username>
    <password>mypassword</password>
  </account>
  <account>
    ...
  </account>
</accounts>
```

In this case, I should be able to select only those websites where I use a particular password or username, for example.

If possible, I'd like to accomplish this just using a web browser or something such as them. No web servers or other daemons should be running on my machine as I don't want much overhead for such simple things.

Let me know if the question is not clear enough.

Thank you.

Comment: Single-user application?

Comment: yes, the only user of this application is me.

Comment: It might be technically possible - but do you really want to?!?! XML is verbose, uses lots of space, and is definitely nowhere near as well suited for querying data as a SQL database... use tools appropriately: a **database** is for storing and querying data, **XML** is for data exchange and import/export

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen [XQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/xquery/default.asp) ?

> XQuery is to XML what SQL is to
>   database tables.

Various implementations exist, including [this in-browser](http://www.zorba-xquery.com/index.php/xquery-in-the-browser-xqib/) version.

Comment: never heard of xquery before. i tried with the wikipedia article, that says it is somewhat related to XSLT. i already now (a very little amount) of XSLT. which one should i study?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Sedna](http://www.modis.ispras.ru/sedna/), [eXist](http://www.exist-db.org/) and [BaseX](http://basex.org/), these appear to be both open source and alive.

Comment: Damn... Seriously, I worked for 3 months on a similar project (I even did a PHPMyAdmin for my XML DB) just to see those answers...

Comment: @Shikiryu: No offense — it was a 45sec googling session. Probably your project is not famous enough yet, just wait :)

Comment: Oh, didn't say that this way. I didn't reference it so it can't be found from a google search ;) Was saying that because despite my small search (which obviously wasn't that good), I've never find a XML as SQL project. That's why I started mine... for nothing...

Answer (score 0):

There are two main classes of XML databases: those that do "only XML", of which the best known are probably eXist as an open source solution, and MarkLogic as a commercial product; and those that do XML alongside relational data, which is possible with DB2, SQL server, and Oracle. All offer XQuery (sometimes with extensions or restrictions) as the main query language. If your data is naturally hierarchic and already represented in XML, then you should certainly consider these products rather than converting your data into the tabular form required for storage in a relational database - which is basically wasted effort.